# .plot() method doesn't return what I expected

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe contains sales data, I would like to count values in specific column and show top 5 results in the bar chart. I code this in PyCharm Edu 3.5.1:

```
df['Province'].value_counts(sort=True)[:5].plot(kind ='barh')
```

but I got this:

```
Axes(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
```

by removing .plot() the code return the result as expected :

```
Ontario             1826
British Columbia    1126
Saskachewan          913
Alberta              865
Manitoba             793
```

I know the other way to plot the top 5, but wondering why did the .plot() that I tried in the first place not work?

Comment: It returns an Axes object as the documentation says. What's unexpected?

Comment: What did not work? If you get the expected results without calling `.plot` why do you bother calling it?

Comment: The thing is I expected to get a horizontal bar chart instead!

Comment: According to what? Where are you the code? Terminal? Jupyter? IDLE?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. in PyCharm Edu

Comment: if you have `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` have you tried `plt.show()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually show the plot, not only create it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = ... # dataframe creation
df['Province'].value_counts(sort=True)[:5].plot(kind ='barh')

plt.show()
```